# Canadian overstayed a US visit by one year what is the penality and when can he return to the US?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, canadian-citizens, overstaying

A Canadian was recently denied a weekend visit from Toronto to NY due to two previous overstays for about a year.

- What is the the penalty for this overstay?
- How does he correct this so the next planned weekend doesn't get denied?

Comment: it's my understanding that this is permanent. It was for my uncle, anyway. I recommend you contact a US consulate for advice specific to your situation.

Comment: How the [....] do you overstay for a _year_? O.O

Comment: Doesn't answer my question he was engaged to a US citizen planning on marrying. He overstayed by 1 year. Not so hard to believe. He was not working.

Comment: fascinating, I don't know how you'd correct that problem. I bet, there are sub-specialities of immigration attorneys who take care of this.

Comment: Did he overstay with more or less than one year (here, the exact duration of the overstay is relevant). When did he overstay? Did he leave the US voluntarily before the institution of removal proceedings?

Comment: He was in NY about 3 years ago and overstayed 1 year. Went back to Canada for a short time. Then she moved to Tennessee and he overstayed 1 year. They broke up 12/2013 so he went back on his own. Do you know what his penalty would be? When can he come back to the states?

Comment: @CarrieZiegler by "overstayed 1 year" do you mean that he was in the US continuously for 18 months? ("Canadian visitors are generally granted a stay in the U.S. for up to six months at the time of entry." -- http://canada.usembassy.gov/visas.html)

Comment: @CarrieZiegler one should also be careful about the purpose of visit, independent of the question of overstaying: "A visitor who intends to live, work or study in the U.S. may be permanently barred from the U.S." (same source).  So the fact that he overstayed could be taken to imply that he had misrepresented the purpose of his visit.

Comment: He did stay a total of 18 months. 1 yr greater than he should. They were planning on getting married.

Comment: @CarrieZiegler: Unless you provide a detailed description of the situation, noone will be able to give you any senseful answer. If he (or she?) actually overstayed his visa once, the first violation would impose at least a three year ban from entering the US again. If he still did so, he has not only overstayed, but violated an entry ban, which may cause a permanent ban from reentering the US. What of all this is actually on record by the US authorities?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: Canadian visitors generally enter without an I-94, and do not automatically accrue unlawful presence, no matter how long they stay. If there is no unlawful presence, then there is no unlawful presence ban.

Comment: "Doesn't answer my question he was engaged to a US citizen planning on marrying" which is why such people are permanently banned.

Answer (score 4):

On his previous entries when he overstayed, did he receive an I-94 (paper or electronic) upon entry? Canadian visitors are usually not given I-94s. One generally only starts accruing "unlawful presence" after staying beyond the date on the I-94. If he did not get an I-94 (as is usual for Canadian visitors), then he does not automatically accrue "unlawful presence" even if he overstays. If he has no unlawful presence, then he has no ban. (There is a 3-year or 10-year ban for accruing 180 days or 1 year, respectively, of "unlawful presence", and then departing the U.S.)

Just because he has no ban does not mean they have to let him in. It just means he is not automatically denied entry. But the immigration officer at the border always has the discretion to deny entry to a visitor, especially one who has overstayed in the past. Since he has no ban, he does not file a waiver (because there is no ban to "waive"). He can just hope that they will let him in. There is no way to guarantee him entry.

Answer (score 0):

The penalty for an overstay of six months to a year is a ban on entry for 3 years. The penalty for more than a year is a ban on entry for 10 years. That's why it's important to be precise about the time of overstay. I don't know how a second offence would be viewed. You can apply for a waiver of this period, but with two offences I wouldn't hold out much hope.

Your friend should probably be reconciled to staying home for a while, or if that's not possible, getting professional legal advice.

Comment: It's not "overstay"; it's "unlawful presence". Canadian visitors generally do not get an I-94 with a date when entering, and do not automatically accrue unlawful presence.