# What happens if Canadian Citizens overstay in United States?

Tags: usa, overstaying, canadian-citizens

Someone who is visiting Florida and goes over the “6 month” deadline. What happens if they were to re-enter Canada? How much trouble is to be had if they were found out? Currently I've overstayed for about a week, but don't look to return to Canada anytime soon.

Comment: Related:  [Canadian citizen overstayed in the US by 10 days 6 years ago](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/113537/canadian-citizen-overstayed-in-the-us-by-10-days-6-years-ago) and [Canadian overstayed a US visit by one year what is the penality and when can he return to the US?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36802/canadian-overstayed-a-us-visit-by-one-year-what-is-the-penality-and-when-can-he)  ...

Comment: From those questions, it seems like there's not an *automatic* ban.  Canadian citizens don't generally receive I-94s with dates of departure, and so do not accrue "unlawful presence".  But even if the ban isn't automatic, the person stands a chance of being turned away the next time they try to enter the US, at the discretion of the CBP official at the border.

Comment: Also, note that if you stay more than 182 days in the US [you can run the risk of being liable for US income tax.](https://www.theglobeandmail.com/investing/personal-finance/taxes/article-snowbirds-be-warned-spending-too-much-time-in-the-us-can-trigger/)  But that's not really a travel issue per se.

Comment: Oh hey, here's another related thread:  [Canadian parents 8 month stay in USA.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/130830/canadian-parents-8-month-stay-in-usa)  The health-insurance angle mentioned in one of the answers there is quite important.